# Liferay Multilevel approval in 6.2

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I have implemented three level workflow for custom asset in liferay 6.2
Approver 1 
Approver 2
Approver 3

If approver2 or Approver 3 is reject the content task is assigned back to Approver 1. My question is now how can i allow Approver1 to edit the rejected content in Myworkflow task?

I can use WorkflowHandlerRegistryUtil.startWorkflowInstance method in my own jsp but it will create a new task instead of retriggring the rejected task

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Please be more specific

Comment: Hii  Olaf, i have implemented 3 level workflow for custom portlet, if approver3 is rejecting task ,task will be assigned back to the approver1(editor). Now Editor want to change the content based on the Approver3's  review comment.so how can i allow editor to edit the content.By default in MyWorkflow task, editor is able to view the content but there is no option to edit the content.

Comment: or i can give editor separate screen where he can edit/update the content but new workflow task will be triggered

Comment: It's that approver able to edit that article outside of workflow? Might be just plain permissions to the article